# How to add header file by script?

Tags: bash

I want to add a sentence to header of a file using bash script, I tried

```
echo "#define Block $i">>mypro.cpp
```

but it add '#define Block $i' to it's end.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `sed` :

```
[romano:~/tmp] % echo test >! test.c       
[romano:~/tmp] % sed -i -e "1i #include" test.c
[romano:~/tmp] % cat test.c 
#include
test
```

...just take care of the correct quoting.

More verbose: `sed -i` means to edit the file (the last argument) in place; the command `"NiSomething"` **i**nsert *Something* at line *N*.

PD this works on Linux and (GNU sed) 4.2.2 --- [POSIX `sed` require a stricter syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078926/2907484).

Comment: If you omit the address (the *N* in your example) doesn't it make the insertion before *every* line?

Comment: @steeldriver Oops, you're right. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Luminous --- if it worked for you please mark the question as answered, see http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers